# How to check if an image to image homography is "reasonable" using matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Intro - In case you don't know what a [homography (computer vision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision)) is

I'm working with some image processing problems where I extract a bunch of points of interest in two images which may or may not have the same subject.

So here's an example of two matching images and the points of interest that may match (and do match in this example):

[image]

Using a C++ library called `opencv` I can get a best fitting homography matrix that transforms points from image 1 into those from image 2. The idea is then to take the inverse of this matrix and use that to warp the perspective of image 2 such that it looks like image 1. The matrix for this particular example is:

[image]

So here's an example of a bad match. First the original keypoint pairings

[image]

and now with the second image warped according to the homography that was found:

[image]

Obviously this is rather "unreasonable"

#### The question

I need a way to tell if a homography is reasonable or not. My linear algebra isn't that great, but my best guesses would be to check:

- **The eigenvalues**. I'd guess that these need to be real and positive, and not insanely far off 1. For my reasonable homography example they are `[0.47, 0.74, 1.01]`. For my unreasonable homography they are `[66.83, 1.02 + 2.08i, 1.02 - 2.08i]`. I just don't know if I'm right though. Would a reasonable homography have negative or complex eigenvalues? I think I know what a negative means (something like a flip along a certain axis), but I'm not sure what a complex eigenvalue means here.
- **The determinant**. I'm just guessing this shouldn't be insanely far off 1 and should be positive. For my reasonable homography example it is 0.35. For my unreasonable homography it is 359.08. BUT I have found unreasonable homographies with determinants fairly close to 1.

So can someone please comment on my ideas and perhaps introduce better ones?

Comment: Doesnt opencv give a goodness of fit score?

Comment: @Alexander A complex eigenvalue means that there's a rotational aspect to the transformation; I don't see any reason to rule that out.

Comment: The principled way is to measure the sum-squared-error of the distances between the target locations and the optimal transformed locations.  This allows you to rank transforms, but any rigid criterion depends upon the image analysis task at hand.

Comment: @Alexander As a metric for the "reasonableness" of the homography, I'd actually recommend the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices), i.e. the ratio between the smallest and largest singular values (as opposed to eigenvalues)

Comment: @user619894 that's a good question. According to the docs it looks like not https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have no knowledge of the optimal transformed location. My end goal is to match images. The trick I'm doing is, to check for a reasonable homography. Pairs with reasonable homographies get good match scores.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare For details on that: [as I explain here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/887438/81360), the condition number conveys the extent to which the homography "squishes" space.

Comment: the docs show that there is a "confidence" value.

Comment: @user619894 that is an input parameter. And I've just tested to see if it helps with rejecting what I need to and it does not. Thanks for checking though

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks! I'm still thinking through it. That squishiness is exactly what I was going for with the eigenvalues. The condition number for my reasonable transformation was 4e5 and for my unreasonable one 2e6 (calculated with [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html) - see notes subheading). I feel like I need some way to normalise things, or at least know where to set a boundary.

Comment: Also 4e5 seems awfully large for the ratio of the major to minor axis of that ellipsoid.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Ah, I agree with your assessment. That's surprising

Comment: @BenGrossmann I should also spend some time understanding the interpretation of that matrix. It's a 3x3 so it's no obvious to me what the physical interpretation of that ellipsoid is.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10972438/2476977) to be helpful

Comment: @AlexanderSoare There are also some questions in the "Linked" column on the right side of the page that you might find helpful

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for that

Comment: @BenGrossmann I read through them and didn't actually find them to be more insightful than your points. Neither did they explain the issue with the condition number being so large. But I posted an answer below which attempts to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've almost figured this one out. In the comments @BenGrossmann mentions condition number as a good way of evaluation how much a matrix "squishes" space. This is great, but it didn't work right away.

$H$ (the homogoraphy matrix) for my "reasonable" example was on the order of 4e5 which indicates an extreme amount of "squishing".

So to understand what's going on we need to understand what the homography matrix actually does. *HINT*: It isn't the only thing required for the transformation. It's a 3x3 matrix because we are actually transforming the points of a plane in 3d space:

[image]

So consider a point on our input plane $[x', y']^\intercal$. When applying a homography we actually put the plane at $z=1$ so that point is: $[x', y', 1]^\intercal$. Then there's a **two step process** to get to our transformed point:

1. Get $[x, y, z] = H[x', y', 1]$. But we aren't done because now our output plane has a varying $z$ component. So the next step explains how to get back into the 2D world of an image.
2. Divide by z to put the point back at $z=1$ to get $[x/z, y/z, 1]$ (not explicitly shown in diagram). This makes sense because if the transformed plane's normal is not parallel to $\hat{z}$, then that means visually that parts of it are further away from the "observer" and therefore appear smaller.

In more mathematical terms, we say that the homography applies the transformation of each point *up to a scale factor* (warning: the input points and output points are flipped in this screenshot relative to my notation):

[image]

So now that we have the computer vision specifics out of the way we can go back to the math. We now know it's not sensible to calculate the condition number of all of $H$ because it's possible to have a perfectly reasonable transformation which translates the input plane along the $z$ axis without touching the $x$ and $y$ coordinates like so:

$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In which case the plane would be translated 4 units in the direction of $\hat{z}$. This would not be an overly unreasonable homography. It would just mean that we make an object look further away. But the condition number would be 5 which indicates a fair bit of squishing.

As another example, let's look at the actual homography matrix from my "reasonable" homography:

$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.73 & -0.4 & 197.41 \\ 0.15 & 0.45 & -57.61 \\ 0 & 0 & 1.17
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The mechanism here is different. The values 197.41 and -57.61 indicate a translation in the $x$, $y$ directions. The input image is about 512x512 pixels so these translations are not so unreasonable. But the matrix is ill-conditioned (condition number is ~4e5) because small changes in $z$ yield large changes in the response. **But since $z$ is fixed, this should not matter.**

The trick then is to take the condition number of the first two columns of $H$ only. Then we are omitting the $z$-dependence of the transformation, which should be irrelevant because we know $z$ will always be fixed to 1 on the input.

When I do this I get a condition number of 1.7 for my "reasonable" homography, and condition numbers of 5+ for "unreasonable" homographies.

I think the last step, which I have not addressed here, is to have some limit on how far along the z-axis I should allow my ouput to be translated. After all, if I translate the ouput to z=100, then the resulting image will be tiny, and therefore rather unreasonable. I believe that by simply looking at the bottom right entry of the matrix, we know a fair bit about the amount of translation. Combining that knowledge with a reasonable condition number for the first two columns of $H$, we should have a pair of totally descriptive criteria for the purpose of the question.

I'm still not 100% sure I'm right so I'll leave this question open and hopefully someone will comment on my reasoning.

Comment: This is an interesting heuristic, but I think that this will overestimate the "niceness" of the transformation if the $z$-axis is parallel or nearly parallel to the target plane ($\pi$ in the figure).

Comment: Good point. Was thinking about that. But wouldn't that be incorporated in the condition number. See, when I omit dependence of $z$ on the input plane that doesn't mean I don't care about it on the output plane. I'm calculating the condition number of a $H'$ where $H'[x',y']^\intercal = [x,y,z]^\intercal$. Without knowing the exact mechanism, I'm told the condition number should be large if the output varies wildly wrt the input. Isn't that the case with what you're saying? That is, $z$ will vary a lot with changes in $[x',y']$